# Pregunta sobre super, extends get y set en javascript

Tags: javascript, clase

soy nuevo en esto, tengo una duda=>
Mi clase superheroe podra hacer cosas que tiene su clase padre Persona, por eso encarni puede gritar, pero como lo hago al reves, para que una persona pueda tener superpoderes?
Todo esto no tiene nada que ver con get y set no? Tengo entendido que el metodo get almacena una propiedad de su PROPIA CLASE, pero que podria hacer con set aqui, y como podria hacer para que una persona tenga superpoderes? 
Muchas gracias

```js
class Persona{
  constructor(nombre, apellido, edad, cm, hijos, celiacos){
    this._nombre = nombre;
    this._apellido = apellido;
    this._edad = edad;
    this._cm = cm;
    this._hijos = hijos;
    this._celiacos = celiacos;
  }
  get presentacion(){ 
    return  'Hola mi nombre es ' + this._nombre + ' y tengo ' + this._edad + 'años';
  }

  gritar(volumen = ' a un volumen desconocido'){ // metodo no necesita function
    console.log(this._nombre +  ' he pegado un grito' + volumen)
  }
}

let amigo1 = new Persona('ivan', 'garcia lopez', 33, 185, false, true)
let amigo2 = new Persona('Fran', 'Manrique', 33, 185, false, true)

console.log(amigo1.presentacion);
amigo1.gritar(' a un volumen estratosferico')
amigo2.gritar();


class Superheroe extends Persona{
  constructor(nombre, apellidos, edad, altura, celiaco, hijos, poderes){
    super(nombre, apellidos, edad, altura, celiaco, hijos);
    this._poderes = poderes;
  }

  relatarPoder(){
    console.log('Tengo ' + this._poderes.length + ' poderes y el primero es ' + this._poderes[0]);
  }

  get misPoderes(){ 
    return this._poderes;
  }
}
let poderes = ['volar', 'escupir fuego', 'matar']
let wonderWoman = new Superheroe('encarni', 'garcia', 35, 178, false, false, poderes);
wonderWoman.gritar(); // Puede gritar ya que extiendo persona a mi superheroe
wonderWoman.relatarPoder();
amigo2.relatarPoder(); // AMIGO 2 NO PUEDE TENER PODER
```

Comment: No es esa la idea. Las personas no tienen superpoderes, los superhéroes sí. Como la clase `Superheroe` extiende la clase `Persona` una instancia de la clase `Superheroe` tiene todas las características de la clase `Persona` más las propias de la clase `Superheroe`. Sin embargo una instancia de la clase `Persona` tiene únicamente las características de esta clase.

Comment: Ya se, vamos que no se puede? Se que no tiene logica pero se podria hacer al reves? Gracias por tus multiples respuestas =)

Comment: No. La jerarquía de clases es eso: una jerarquía. Va únicamente en una dirección. Puede haber muchas clases que extiendan una clase, por ejemplo la clase `Vehiculo` puede ser extendida para crear las clases `Coche`, `Camion`, `Furgoneta`, `Motocicleta`, `Bicicleta`, ... De esta forma podremos decir que una `Motocicleta` es un `Vehiculo`, pero un `Vehiculo` no tiene porqué ser una `Motocicleta`

Comment: Si planteas qué es lo que tratas de conseguir, podríamos explicarte cómo hacerlo en javascript.